# How to manage attachments in Siebel data mappings?

Tags: siebel

We have a Siebel 7.8 application with two integration objects, and both have an integration component for the attachments. One of them defines the attachment field as `DTYPE_ATTACHMENT`, while the other defines it as `DTYPE_TEXT` (it's used in an inbound web service which reads the base64 data string and writes it to a file on disk).

I'm trying to convert data from an IO to the other using UI data mappings and the `EAI Data Transformation Engine` service, but I have been unsuccesfull so far:

- If I transform the data from `DTYPE_ATTACHMENT` to `DTYPE_TEXT`, it doesn't raise any error, but the attachment base64 data is lost and I only get the row_id in the resulting XML.
- If I transform the data from `DTYPE_TEXT` to `DTYPE_ATTACHMENT`, I get this error:

  > Source expression generated attachment ID 'MDEyMzQ1Njc [...] DEy8/W3CDCys7U2w==' but the corresponding attachment cannot be found. (SBL-EAI-04058)

Is there any way in which I can convert data from one of the integration objects to the other, without losing the base64 data? I don't care if the transformation is "attachment to text" or "text to attachment", I can build what I need either way. I can't change the definition of the integration objects, but I can create a new one to use as an intermediate step, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give up. It cannot be done. It's impossible and any further attempt to solve it will cause the known universe to implode. Thanks, Siebel!

However...

I have found a quite simple workaround for my requeriment. In fact, it's so simple I can't believe it took me 4 days to figure it out.

Instead of trying to force a `DTYPE_TEXT` field into a `DTYPE_ATTACHMENT` one, or viceversa, I have created two versions of the field in the output integration object: `content (DTYPE_ATTACHMENT)`, and `contentText (DTYPE_TEXT)`. Now, the two fields have a different name, but they share the `External Name` and `XMLTag` properties (`content`). For Siebel they're different fields, and I can address them differently in the data mapping; however, once the data transformation has been executed, they both become `<content>`, and therefore the external system on the other side of the web service won't notice any difference. Done!